# string to int currency formatting

Tags: ruby

When there is a string value such as 3.76 how can this be converted into a int cent value in this case 376.

I was thinking of using sprintf to remove the dot then convert to int but can't work out the syntax. How would I do this and is it the best way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

removing the dot is rather easy:

```
cent.gsub!(/\./,"")
```

will remove the dot.

To get an int, simply call the integer constructor:

```
Integer(cent)
```

Of course you can combined the two operations:

```
Integer(cent.gsub!(/\./,""))
```

Comment: I did this, pence = Integer(@card_balance)
@card_balance is a string 3.76

it comes up with an error invalid value for Integer: "3.76" (ArgumentError)

Comment: pence = Integer(@card_balalnce.gsub(/\./,"")) should work as well

Comment: pence = (@card_balalnce.to_f * 100).to_i

Comment: I don't think you want to cast to float. That introduces rounding errors and precision, which could create hard-to-find bugs.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean ANSI C and have a string value that you would like to convert into an int.

int cents = (atof(myString) * 100.0);

atof converts a string to a double (or float depending on compiler and platform), then just multiply with 100 to move the decimal pointer two steps right.

very simple :)

Answer (score 0):

Removing the dot only works if you always have two decimals, i.e. fine for "3.76", but not for "3.7" or even "3".

- "3.76" => 376
- "3.7" => 37 instead of 370
- "3"   => 3  instead of 300

Best solution might be to convert it to a float first, then multiply by 100 and only then turn it into an int using round. If you can have more then 2 decimals you'll need to decide on a rounding scheme. For instance:

```
("3.76".to_f * 100.0).round
```

Note that [converting from a float to an int using to_i isn't accurate](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/178503), as mentioned by Clint in a comment to this answer.

Comment: This answer is wrong and misleading. Please read http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/178503

Comment: Here is an example on my system: ("8.54".to_f * 100).to_i => 853 [WRONG]

Comment: Cheers for pointing that out, I've updated my answer to use round instead of to_i.

Answer (score -1):

I think this is a bit more ruby-ish instead of calilng Integer(cent) and doing weird substitutions.

```
(cent * 100).to_i
```

Comment: `("3.76" * 100).to_i => 3` - Amsterdam, we have a problem!